# Async Co-Routine in Kotlin

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine

I never use async in Kotlin. I'm not sure whether I understand is correctly.

I need that the method buttonChange(result) wait the thread is finish, to obtain the result.

```
fun sendConnection(view: View) {

    var result = ""

    if (!connected) {

                async {

                    val runnable = Runnable()
                    {
                        result =  me.connect("connection")
                    }
                    val threadSend = Thread(runnable)
                    threadSend.start()
                    }
                    buttonChange(result)
                }

             catch (e: Exception) {}

        } else {

            try {

                async {

                    val runnable = Runnable()
                    {
                        result =  me.connect("disconnection")
                    }
                    val threadSend = Thread(runnable)
                    threadSend.start()
                }
                buttonChange(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. This also looks like Android in which case you probably don't want to wait on results anyways because you have to use callbacks on the ui thread to handle results from other threads. Btw, your `Runnable` does not use the code in `{}` afterwards, the syntax in Kotlin is `val runnable = Runnable{ println("Hello from runnable") }` (or [`object : Runnable() {}` syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions)). Threads + runnables are also not necessary with `async` because that already uses a thread to execute the async code.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you should use is `async/await`.

It'll return a `Deferred` from `async { }` which you can use to call `await()` on. Since `buttonChange` seems to need the `UI` context, you might need to launch the coroutines as well.

```
launch(UI) {
    try {
        val result = async { me.connect("disconnection") }
        buttonChange(result.await())
    } catch (_: Exception) { }
}
```

You should not create a thread manually.